# Image size for Bootstrap page with 960 width

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap page that is responsive but i have limited max width to 960px. Im testing to have images that is 960px wide for all columnsizes with img-responsive class. It looks fine even in a col-8 + col-4 grid for example.

Whats the ideal image size these days when we use retina devices etc? Is it fine with 960 width image or should i go wider?

Comment: There's no such a thing like ideal image, there too many formats nowadays, if you have some time take a look at this dpi guide http://sebastien-gabriel.com/designers-guide-to-dpi/

Comment: Ok that seems to be a good guide but if i have a col-6 col-6 grid and images is 450px to fit the grids. Should i use retina size x2 = 900px? Will it look bad otherwise for retina devices? @AlexDom

Comment: Actually photographs look okay, not as crisp as an image that's 2x the size, but logos and icons look fugly. http://adaptive-images.com/ is a server side method for detecting retina and serving up a high density image without changing your markup. However, read this carefully: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/compressive-images.html you can compress an image that's twice the size at 0% compression and on retina it looks great and takes up less space than one sized down to the non-retina size